# jquery ui autocomplete not showing result

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

so i'm using jquery ui autocomplete instead of combobox to make it easier for my users to select hundreds of products from database.

```
$(function() {
    $(".autocomplete").autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({ 
                'url': "http://localhost/project/index.php/product/search_data/",
                'data': { 'txt_product_name': $('#txt_product_name').val()},
                'dataType': "json",
                'type': "POST",
                'success': function(data){
                    response(data);
                }
            })
        }, 
        minLength: 2,
        focus: function( event, ui ) {
            $(".txt_product_id").val(ui.item.product_id);
            return false;
        },
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            $( ".txt_product_id" ).val(ui.item.product_id);
            $( ".txt_product_code" ).val(ui.item.product_code);
            $( ".txt_product_name" ).val(ui.item.product_name);

            return false;
        }       
    }).data("autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
        return $( "<li></li>" )
            .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
            .append( "<a>" + item.product_code + "<br>" + item.product_name + "</a>" )
            .appendTo(ul);
    };  
});
```

firebug tells me that php successfully generates requested data, like below.

```
[
    {"product_id":"92","product_code":"TURE3052","product_name":"Choose Your Own Adventure"},
    {"product_id":"89","product_code":"UMPS3447","product_name":"Goosebumps"},
    {"product_id":"15","product_code":"ROSE7302","product_name":"The Name of the Rose"},
    {"product_id":"34","product_code":"LIFE1226","product_name":"The Purpose Driven Life"}
]
```

but somehow, the result does not show.

any ideas?

i copied parts of the codes from http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#custom-data. i have tested the example and it worked.

Comment: you say you copied the code from the example, did you also copy the CSS styling that comes with it? because the flyout list of options you get on autocomplete relies a lot on css to be displayed correctly.

Comment: oh, and firebug tells you the service returns correct data, but, and this might be obvious but it's not for some people, you don't by accident have another (possible unrelated) javascript error? because if you have one, this can be blocking for some other javascript code...

Comment: @Sander i have included the css but nothing's really changed. yes, it occurs to me that i might have possible unrelated javascript error. but since it's unrelated, i have no idea where to start.

Comment: then you will need to clear those first, any javascript error can block the script from executing so you will need to clear those first, if you have trouble with that you can always post your script and error in a new question here though.

Answer (score 0):

ok, i don't quite understand how and why, but it so happened that i need to create clones of the autocomplete textbox. for that purpose, i use live() in order for jquery to catch the event of new clone. i modify the above code to look like below:

```
$(function() {
    $(".autocomplete").live('keyup.autocomplete', function() {
        $(".autocomplete").autocomplete({
            source: function(request, response) {
                $.ajax({ 
                    'url': "http://localhost/project/index.php/product/search_data/",
                    'data': { 'txt_product_name': $('#txt_product_name').val()},
                    'dataType': "json",
                    'type': "POST",
                    'success': function(data){
                        response(data);
                    }
                })
            }, 
            minLength: 2,
            focus: function( event, ui ) {
                $(".txt_product_id").val(ui.item.product_id);
                return false;
            },
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                $( ".txt_product_id" ).val(ui.item.product_id);
                $( ".txt_product_code" ).val(ui.item.product_code);
                $( ".txt_product_name" ).val(ui.item.product_name);

                return false;
            }       
        }).data("autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
            return $( "<li></li>" )
                .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
                .append( "<a>" + item.product_code + "<br>" + item.product_name + "</a>" )
                .appendTo(ul);
        };  
    })
});
```

as i say, i don't understand how and why, but the autocomplete result does show up. felt a little relieved. but since it is a must for me to understand my own work, i think i have to figure out the explanation.

ideas?